# Export sas table to CSV

Tags: sas

I have created a table in sas and Want to export to a CSV but I am facing a problem that when I export to csv the AGE value of 10-20 becomes OCT-20. I want to see as it is like sas table. How can I do it.

```
    ID   Age    Value
    1   0-10    3154
    2   35-45   0
    3   10-20   9527
    4   10-20   3856
    5   20-35   8111
    6   0-10    105
    7   10-20   5500
    8   10-20   5500
    9   0-10    1918
    10  0-10    2819


PROC EXPORT DATA=FORECAST
   OUTFILE='\\pwc-storage\BP&D\IMP_OUT\FORECAST.CSV'
   DBMS=csv REPLACE;
RUN;
```

CSV out put

```
ID  Age Value
1   0-10    3154
2   0-10    0
3   Oct-20  9527
4   Oct-20  3856
5   20-35   8111
6   0-10    105
7   Oct-20  5500
8   Oct-20  5500
9   0-10    1918
10  0-10    2819
```

Comment: You mean "becomes OCT-20" when opened in Excel, right?

Comment: yes, when  open CSV I see OCT-20, It will get chaged to date format

Comment: And if you open the csv in notepad?

Comment: if I open the csv in notepad, The Value is perfect ie,10-20

Comment: This is really an Excel question since SAS is exporting the field correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is caused by Excel trying to treat some values in AGE field as Date.

You should run Import Wizard in Excel to import the csv and mark field AGE as TEXT instead of default General option.

Alternatively, you could e.g. create a view on top of FORECAST table to add a single quote prefix to AGE values, so that you force Excel to treat it as text:

```
data FORECAT_EXPORT_VIEW / view=FORECAT_EXPORT_VIEW;
    length AGE $10;
    set FORECAST;
    AGE = catt("'", AGE);
run;
```

You'll run PROC EXPORT on top of view.

Comment: Yes its working but the length is not correct, its showing as '10-2 and '20-3 I tried with different length still its showing AGE '10-2 in sas itself

Comment: Be sure to put LENGTH statement before SET statement, otherwise original length will be used, which seems has no more room for additional character (prefix) and the values seem truncated ( '10-2 instead of '10-20 ).

Comment: I used the statement as length AGE $10; still i am getting same '10-2